# Converting xml to a readable format for translation

Tags: xml, translation

I need to send an XML document to a translator. It would be better for the translator to get it in an easy to read format such as doc or even text. Are there any options people here could suggest?

The xml is of the following format -

```
<Q>
    <Q1>
        <A>text for translation</A> 
        <An>text for translation</An> 
        <An>text for translation</An> 
        <An>text for translation</An> 
        <An>text for translation</An> 
        <C>3</C> 
    </Q1>



</Q>
```

Comment: This is not valid XML. Is `</Q1></Q1>` correct?

Comment: i messed that up - corrected now

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT to transform it into XML Word Doc format.

Or use the [XSL FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp) translations.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON. Google for "XML 2 Json" for converters.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for this sort of thing is TMX, and the Omega-T open source tool is out there.